# How fill the form of payment amazon using SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: forms, selenium-webdriver, iframe, screen-scraping

This is a one part of my code, here I do click in 'Add a credit or debit card' and switch the frame, for the I will proceed fill the form but have this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="pp-QqmNYT-14"]"}
```

This is my part of code:

```
self.__driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Add a credit or debit card').click()
self.__driver.switch_to.frame(self.__driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
self.__driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pp-QqmNYT-14"]').send_keys("user admin")
self.__driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'addCreditCardNumber').send_keys(self.cc)
```

This is the form that I want fill:
[https://www.amazon.sg/gp/prime/pipeline/membersignup](https://www.amazon.sg/gp/prime/pipeline/membersignup?ms3_c=e1333c6be88e9a5a5014bf38bebc915e)

Comment: Did you check there is only one frame in the page you are accessing?

Comment: I found a second iframe but there is nothing its a iframe empy

Comment: So what if your switch_to.frame() is switching to the 2nd one which is empty. So, you have to rewrite your switch_to statement. What are the attributes of the frame you are trying to switch to? Like name, id

Comment: The second (empty iframe) is inside the first iframe, and the first iframe that I try to switch is id='pp-KHHq3T-44' but I cant use <self.__driver.switch_to.frame(self.__driver.find_element_by_id('pp-KHHq3T-44'))> because i get this error <selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="pp-KHHq3T-44"]"}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
self.__driver.switch_to.frame(self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//iframe[contains(@name,'ApxSecureIframe')]'))
```