# How to acces a iframe whitout src SELENIUM

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I trying to switch to frame but if I use:

> self.__driver.switch_to.frame(self.__driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))

I get a iframe empy and I cant acces to input inside of the frame.

If I use this:

```
WebDriverWait(self.__driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'pp-EY0PvP-44')))
```

I got this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element

This is the html:
[HTML image link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-rlfxP-X01hKaXdS5QAqAMESP3rncTrB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The solution to my error is here in another post that I made:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840486/how-fill-the-form-of-payment-amazon-using-selenium-python/67852295#67852295

Comment: Do not vandalize your post by replacing its contents with gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ‘id’ of the iframe also as far as I am concerned with the Selenium docs.

Comment: I cant acces the id, i get `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

Comment: That Id might not be stable. Or maybe there’s another iframe involved or a timing issue? We need to see more of your code and the html.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` to switch to **iframe** like below :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@name, 'ApxSecureIframe-pp-')]")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```